# Looking for a publicly accessible online academic and/or peer-reviewed site for reading about Bibles with printing or translation errors.

Tags: bible-versions

I am undertaking a Bible study to learn more about it and currently we are investigating whether any Bibles actually existed that had actual verifiable errors in them, as the person leading the study fully embraces the inerrancy of the Bible.

I did a quick check on Wikipedia and found a long list of Bibles that have been released with errors:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_errata

I especially note the The Blasphemous Comma Bible, The Wicked Bible, and The Printers Bible.

However he does not accept Wikipedia as a valid source and would like me to furnish him with a link to something much more academic/scholarly and peer-reviewed, which is probably a reasonable request.

Assuming that Wikipedia and other less scholarly sites I have been reading have not gotten it wrong, can anyone here help me find such a website or webpage of an academic nature that confirms the existence of Bibles with mistranslations, misprints, or other errors?

Alternatively, if I have somehow not found the right stack exchange subsite for investigating errors in translation and printing, please direct me to the more proper stack exchange venue for this inquiry.

Comment: Have you followed the sources in the article?

Comment: Assuming you mean the Wikipedia article I referenced, ironically enough it cites very few references, most of which aren't online resources but books I have no access to.

Comment: Have you tried books. Google.com?

Comment: Wasn't aware of books.google.com, thanks for that tip. Will see what I can find.

Comment: NLT ISBN 978-1-4143-2708-2 has a typo in Ex 15:11 on page 67. Probably the other cover editions do too: 978-1-4143-2704-5, -2706-8, -2705-1, -2707-5.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a scholarly article as proof that there can be errors in a bible.  All you need is a spare Bible and a permanent marker.  Change one letter in the text, and there is an error.  There you have it.  Physical proof that there can be errors in a Bible.  No matter what proof you show that a Bible actually had a typo, one could just say that the mistake was made on purpose to disprove the inerrancy of the Bible.  You could go to the museums that house one of the famous Bibles with an error.  You could also go to the museum's websites and search the archives.  But one could say the same of those Bibles, that the errors were made on purpose.

One also doesn't need to look any further than their own Bible to see errors from original manuscripts.  1 Samuel 17 says that David killed Goliath, but 2 Samuel 21:19 says that Elhanan killed Goliath.

> Again there was war at Gob with the Philistines, where Elhanan the son of Jaare-Oregim the Bethlehemite killed the [brother of] Goliath the Gittite, the shaft of whose spear was like a weaver’s beam.

The New King James Version. (1982). (2 Sa 21:19). Nashville: Thomas Nelson.

A footnote from the KJV (which also italicizes "the brother of") says that "the brother of" was supplied from 1 Chr. 20:5.  LEB, which was made to be close to interlinear, omits the additional "the brother of" placing it in a footnote saying that he likely killed the brother of Goliath given the verses I've already shown.  If you really wanted to, you could also go to the Hebrew manuscripts and see that they don't have "the brother of" (or else they also have it supplied in brackets) in their text.  I have an [info-graphic](https://www.logos.com/product/45611/who-killed-goliath) explaining how that error likely happened.

Moreover, if there were no errors in Bible anywhere along the line, then how could there be verses that are included in some English Bible verses and not in others?  How could there be translations that say totally opposite things such as how the Jehovah's Witness Bibles say that Jesus is not God while translations such as KJV say that He is.  They both can't be right.  One or the other must contain some kind of error.

Of course, these misprints don't mean that the Bible is untrustworthy.  If one can believe that God prevents all typos when someone is writing scripture, then it shouldn't be hard to believe that God preserves the Scripture in light of misprints, textual errors, and mistranslated.